# Filter a sharepoint list by created on after e.g. 4pm

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a formula that I can add to only show items created after 4pm yesterday on a sharepoint list please?

Everyday I want to check the list and see what items were created after 4 pm from yesterday till today.

It is an issue tracking list on a sharepoint site linked to a Teams site / sharepoint modern site

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[Today]` to filter the list value. For example:

[image]

This will show items created from yesterday till today.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there anyway to filter it down to be time specific? Today -1 would work but it would show tasks created at e.g. 7 am yesterday?  I was hoping to limit it to only show items from 4pm yesterday till now, so anything before 4pm that is created yesterday is excluded

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such way to filter it down to be time specific with Today.

Answer (score 0):

This might be to overdo it but..

If you can create a calculated column of the type **Number** (without decimals) and use the function `=HOUR([Created])` you can get the hour.

You should now be able to combine the filter to be this:

- *Created is greater than or equal to [Today]-1*
- AND
- *[Hour] is greater than or equal to 16*
- OR
- *Created is equal to [Today]*
- AND
- *HOUR is greater than or equal to 0*

Result in my list (as of 9/4/2020 12:00PM):

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: If I wanted to show everything created Today but after 10 am, would I only need to add 2 filters? 1 = Created = TODAY and another one Hours = greater than or equal to 10?

Comment: Yes, sounds about right to me.